# I want to get URL before last file name

Tags: javascript, file, url

I want to get URL before last file name.
As an example,

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs/index.html*

In the above URL I only want to get

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs*

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs/index.html".replace(/(.*)\/.*/,'$1');
```

or in general

```
url.replace(/(.*)\/.*/,'$1');
```